# Wordpress + Thesis Theme => WPTouch Post Thumbnails don't work?

Tags: plugins

Has anyone managed to get this combination to work and display post thumbnails on the mobile site?

- Wordpress 3.3.1
- Thesis Theme 1.8.3
- WPTouch 1.9.38

I've activated Thesis support for Post Thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 96, 96, true );
```

I know the thumbnails are created, I can see them on the main site. Any idea why WPTouch is not picking these up and instead displaying a default "camera" icon?

The site I'm testing this with is: http://fitness9000.com

Comment: Can you get WPTouch to work on your install of WordPress, using a different Theme, e.g. the default Twenty Eleven Theme? If so, then this is a *Theme-specific* issue that should be directed to the developer, DIYThemes.

Answer (score 1):

Chip, you appear to be correct. I switched back to the default WP theme and there are no post images or thumbnails displayed. In fact, it appears that a theme needs to support Wordpress's new "Featured Image" functionality, which the Thesis Theme currently does not by default.

However, adding:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

to the theme's **custom_functions.php** file enabled Featured Image support and now everything works like I want it to. WPTouch now displays Post Thumnbnails for every post for which a featured image is set.